# What is the most Earth-like planet in the Star Wars galaxy?

Tags: star-wars

In the Star Wars universe, which planet resembles Earth the most, considering these factors:

- Size
- Distance to nearest star/sun
- Population
- Landscape
- Amount of water/land
- Climate
- Variety of species
- Variety of landscapes

Comment: Coruscant is basically an Earth analogue

Comment: @Valorum except it's been paved over.

Comment: @Spencer - Yes, and Coruscant is a bit urban as well.

Comment: @Valorum Heh.  Anyway C's population is at least 125 times Earth's.

Comment: @Spencer - I'm not saying they haven't made a few changes around the place.

Comment: DV reason? Seems like a legitimate question to me especially since the OP lists quantifiable measures of comparison

Comment: @DBPriGuy  -  maybe the downvoters think the question requires too much research, or very specific knowledge.

Comment: @Spencer More specifically, Coruscant's population is 142 times earth's.

Comment: Are we including legends? Because then it's earth, since it does appear in a comic where the millennium falcon winds up on earth in the past and Indiana jones discovers it.

Comment: @CBredlow - That may be the *Star Wars* universe, but not the *Star Wars* galaxy. ;) By definition, a galaxy “far, far away” must be far from our current galaxy, i.e. the Milky Way, and thus not the same as the Milky Way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Probably Corellia

Two important preliminary notes:

- We don’t actually know. Most habitable planets in *Star Wars* have almost certainly not been named, so one of those may actually be the most Earth-like. All we can do is compare the planets presented in canon.
- Many of the planets presented in canon may have biomes other than those we see on-screen.
- *All* the plot-relevant planets in *Star Wars* would be considered incredibly Earth-like by the standards of, say, astronomers. Gravity that’s strong enough to walk, but weak enough to stand up; a breathable atmosphere; life: all of these are the exception in the universe, not the rule. This is undoubtedly a selection effect: no one lives on or cares about the planet with the ammonia atmosphere and twelve times Earth’s gravity.

That said, of the named planets, **Corellia** seems to have the greatest canonical evidence of being like Earth.

- It’s planet-sized, so not a moon.
- It’s not entirely urbanized, unlike Coruscant.
- Humans live there long-term, so it presumably has near-Earth gravity and a breathable atmosphere.
- As for its terrain, the Databank [describes](http://www.starwars.com/databank/corellia) it thus:

  > Forests,  Jungles,  Urban

  So it definitely has at least forests, jungles, and cities, which makes three different terrain types. This beats Scarif, for example.

  However, it also probably has deserts. The sand panther is mentioned in canon (*Star Wars Insider #156*). In Legends, it was known as the [Corellian sand panther](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Corellian_sand_panther), and, as the name implies, lived primarily in deserts. Thus it seems likely that Corellia still has deserts in canon.

Another plausible contender for “most Earth-like” is **Alderaan**, which, although primarily mountainous, can be seen to have oceans, and has also be confirmed to have rain forests.

**Lothal** is another possibility. As we can see from this image of Lothal, it has decently large bodies of water, and otherwise seems to resemble Earth.

[image]

According to the sourcebook *Nexus of Power*, it has such varied terrain as savannahs, freshwater seas, small mountains, and prairies. However, it is not very urbanized.

Comment: I vote for Alderaan. See [this info page](http://www.swtor.com/holonet/planets/alderaan) on SW:TOR's website. Looks almost entirely similar to our own pale blue dot. *So what it's no longer canon? Who cares?*

Comment: It's probably Earth. This is based on the Earth/E.T. Tatooine/E.T. string theory discovered woven into tapestries found on both worlds.    Yes.     Earth is my final answer.

Comment: @Adamant Great job, you cited many sources, you gave a clear answer, and you made sure to include mostly canon answers! +1 (I would give you +2 if I could)